# django query based on dynamic property()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I was wondering if there was a way to use Django's filter() on query sets using a dynamically generated python property using `property()`. I have `first_name` and `last_name` of every user, and I want to filter based on their concatenated name `first_name last_name`. (The reason behind this is that when I do autocomplete I search to see if the query matches first name, last name, or part of the concatenation. I want `John S` to match `John Smith`, for example.

I created a property of `name`:

```
def _get_name(self):
    return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
name = property(_get_name)
```

This way I can call `user.name` to get the concatenated name.

However, if I try to do `User.objects.filter(name__istartswith=query)` I get the error `Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field.`

Any ideas on how to do this? Do I have to create another field in the database to store the full name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`filter()` operates on the database level (it actually writes SQL), so it won't be possible to use it for any queries based on your python code `(dynamic property in your question)`.

This is an answer put together from many other answers in this department : )

Comment: Interesting, nope you cant filter on properties, but you can group existing fields and filter by the group [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19040011/3999748)

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is not entirely true.

For many cases, you can override `get()` in the model manager to `pop` dynamic properties from the keyword arguments, then add the actual attributes you want to query against into the `kwargs` keyword arguments dictionary. Be sure to return a `super` so any regular `get()` calls return the expected result.

I'm only pasting my own solution, but for the `__startswith` and other conditional queries you could add some logic to `split` the double-underscore and handle appropriately.

Here was my work-around to allow querying by a dynamic property:

```
class BorrowerManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        full_name = kwargs.pop('full_name', None)
        # Override #1) Query by dynamic property 'full_name'
        if full_name:
            names = full_name_to_dict(full_name)
            kwargs = dict(kwargs.items() + names.items())
        return super(BorrowerManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

In models.py:

```
class Borrower(models.Model):
    objects = BorrowerManager()

    first_name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=30)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

---

In utils.py (for the sake of context):

```
def full_name_to_dict(full_name):
    ret = dict()
    values = full_name.split(' ')
    if len(values) == 1:
        raise NotImplementedError("Not enough names to unpack from full_name")
    elif len(values) == 2:
        ret['first_name'] = values[0]
        ret['middle_name'] = None
        ret['last_name'] = values[1]
        return ret
    elif len(values) >= 3:
        ret['first_name'] = values[0]
        ret['middle_name'] = values[1:len(values)-1]
        ret['last_name'] = values[len(values)-1]
        return ret
    raise NotImplementedError("Error unpacking full_name to first, middle, last names")
```

Comment: Good! btw you could use something like `isinstance(getattr( self.model, attr ), property)` to check whether argument is property or not. I am doing something in similar way..

Comment: `kwargs = dict(kwargs.items() + names.items())` can be written as `kwargs.update(names)`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and was looking for solution. Taking for granted that a search engine would be the best option (e.g. `django-haystack` with `Elasticsearch`), that's how I would implement some code for your needs using only the Django ORM (you can replace `icontains` with `istartswith`):

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

queryset = User.objects.annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
return queryset.filter(full_name__icontains=value)
```

In my case I didn't know whether the user would insert '`first_name` `last_name`' or viceversa, so I used the following code.

```
from django.db.models import Q, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

queryset = User.objects.annotate(first_last=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name'), last_first=Concat('last_name', Value(' '), 'first_name'))
return queryset.filter(Q(first_last__icontains=value) | Q(last_first__icontains=value))
```

With Django <1.8, you would probably need to resort to `extra` with the SQL `CONCAT` function, something like the following:

```
queryset.extra(where=['UPPER(CONCAT("auth_user"."last_name", \' \', "auth_user"."first_name")) LIKE UPPER(%s) OR UPPER(CONCAT("auth_user"."first_name", \' \', "auth_user"."last_name")) LIKE UPPER(%s)'], params=['%'+value+'%', '%'+value+'%'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it's not possible in django to filter on properties that does not present as a database filed, but what you can do to make cool autocomplete search is something like this:

```
if ' ' in query:
    query = query.split()
    search_results = list(chain(User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=query[0],last_name__icontains=query[1]),
                                    User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=query[1],last_name__icontains=query[0])))
else:
    search_results =  User.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=query)| Q(last_name__icontains=query))
```

This code gives the user of your system a flexibility to start typing either first name or last name and the user will be thankful to you for allowing this.

Comment: Thought about that, but there are some problems. Some people may have spaces in their first or last name, and so splitting it by space may be broken. Otherwise, though, I already have it search either first name or last name. I set up a signal to populate the name field upon creation, though, so it works now. Thanks.